# Unable to use installed python packages

Tags: python, firebase, pip

I'm facing a weird issue. First, I tried installing [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase). It gets installed successfully. Gets showed in `pip3 list` at least. But, when I run the file `database.py` containing

```
import pyrebase
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyrebase
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrebase'
```

Then, I tried with [python-firebase](http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/). I again face the same issue. Installs successfully; is shown in `pip3 list`, but I again get module not found error. Can someone please help me fix this?

**EDIT**

`python3 -m site` gives the following output:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/ankit',
    '/home/ankit/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
    '/home/ankit/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
    '/home/ankit/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/home/ankit/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/ankit/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: How do you run that file? Do you run it with python2 perhaps?

Comment: @Ardweaden no. I run it using `python3 database.py`

Comment: How did you install it? With `pip3`? Can you check if `pip3 --version` and `python3 --version` match (python versions)?

Comment: @KacperFloriański yes, I use `pip3`. The output for those commands are `pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)` and `Python 3.7.4` respectively

Comment: Can you check if the module is in fact included in your Python3.7.4 distribution? You can do it for example by going into Python console and typing `help('modules')`. An example one-liner command could be `python3.8 -c "print(help('modules'))"`, you can also pipe it and grep for `base` or `firebase` etc. Or you could just have a look at site-packages directory of wherever your installation of `python3.7.4` is.

Comment: @KacperFloriański umm no, apparently neither of `pyrebase` or `python-firebase` is shown when I type `help(modules)`

Comment: In that case, I see three possible outcomes: 1. something went really wrong when installing the libraries; 2. they have completely different names (for example after installing `opencv-python` you import it with `import cv2`); 3. You have multiple Python versions on your machine, specifically, multiple 3.7 versions and your `pip3` doesn't match your `python3`. I would presume point 3 is the most likely one.

Comment: @KacperFloriański I have edited the question to include site packages directory (I hope it is indeed what you asked for in the second half of your comment)

Comment: @KacperFloriański 1. No, nothing went wrong. 2. I used the code present here: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#add-pyrebase-to-your-application so don't think that's an issue. 3. That I'd need to check...

Comment: Regarding 3 - I believe what may have happened was: you have already had an installed version of Python3.7 (linux distribution) and then you installed anaconda. Your `pip3` now points to the Linux-based distribution and your `python3` points to your anacoda installation. You can verify it if you call `python3 -m pip install python-firebase` - this will install it using the anaconda-related installation.

Comment: @KacperFloriański should I use `pip3` instead of `pip`? Or it doesn't matter since we have `python3` up front?

Comment: Doesn't matter, `pip3` will just point to `pip` inside some `python3` installation. Edit: `python3 -m pip` says "execute `pip` module using a python installation pointed by `python3`"

Comment: Okay, perfect! I will summarise this conversation into a solution so it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: @KacperFloriański one more question. Is there any way I can resolve this issue permanently?

Comment: Yes, you can point your `pip3` to your conda installation's `pip`. I can include a how-to in a solution later, but there should be enough resources online.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
from firebase import firebase
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've used with `python-firebase`